# ls there a way to go to root view using ModalViewController:

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller

In Xcode 4 I was able to go to the root view where I used a ModalViewController using the following code:

```
[mHomeController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: true];
[mHomeController.view addSubview:mHomeController->adView];
```

mHomeController is a global pointing to the first view controller.

When I upgraded to Xcode 5 I get a error in line:

[mHomeController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: true];
   [mHomeController.view addSubview:mHomeController->adView];

Saying method adView does not exist,

Now, none of my projects will build. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Does it work if you change `mHomeController->adView` to `mHomeController.adView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

// try this and the additional code below
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"POPTOROOTVIEW" object:nil];

//or just this line as it may be that you're popToRoot is called before the modal view is animated off

    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }];
```

Then in another view controller have this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
....
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(popToRootViewPlease) name:@"POPTOROOTVIEW" object:nil];
....
}

- (void)popToRootViewPlease
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self];

}
```

Comment: No did not wprk just goes to the pre view thank  you for the thought